# Parsing multiple json values in linux jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have json string like this:

```
jstring='[{"userQuery":"select name from abc;","user":"abc"},{"userQuery":"select name from xyz;","user":"xyz"},{"userQuery":"select name from ppp;","user":"ppp"}]'
```

I wrote a simple for loop using jq to extract values but not getting the desired result.

```
for i in `echo $jstring | jq '.[] | [.user, .userQuery]'`; do echo ${i}; done
```

With the help of this line : `echo $jstring | jq '.[] | [.user, .userQuery]'`. I am able to extract below info:

```
[ "abc", "select name from abc;"][ "xyz", "select name from xyz;"][ "ppp", "select name from ppp;"]
```

Now, I want two variable "user" & "query" for each array and store that info. 
Eg: For [ "abc", "select name from abc;"] -- user: abc, query: "select name from abc" and store them.

I am not sure how to iterate over json using jq and get individual values and store them.

Comment: do you want to accumulate respective values in an array, like: `user["abc" "xyz" "ppp"]` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: No, I want to build a message and log it or email it. Eg: User: ${user} is running : ${query}.

Comment: Closely related: [Converting a JSON array to a bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717277/converting-a-json-array-to-a-bash-array).

Comment: The underlying question of getting results from jq to bash is commonly asked.  See also these recent ones: [Convert a nested JSON of objects into array into a bash array using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229097/convert-a-nested-json-of-objects-into-array-into-a-bash-array-using-jq) and [Is there a way to read all key-value pairs in the JSON file and then initialize all variables accordingly in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187807/is-there-a-way-to-read-all-key-value-pairs-in-the-json-file-and-then-initialize)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to store them as *shell* variables. With bash you can write:

```
while read -r user query; do 
    echo "user->$user"
    echo "query->$query"
done < <( jq -r '.[] | "\(.user) \(.userQuery)"' <<< "$jstring" )
```

```
user->abc
query->select name from abc;
user->xyz
query->select name from xyz;
user->ppp
query->select name from ppp;
```

The secret sauce is in the formulation of the string inside jq that refers to the object properties with `\(.user)`

I'm assuming that the user name does not contain spaces. Otherwise we have to use a different separator in that string, and use `IFS` with the shell read command.

Comment: @gelnnjackman Thank you for the quick response and answer. This is perfect! I was looking at this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187807/is-there-a-way-to-read-all-key-value-pairs-in-the-json-file-and-then-initialize but couldn't make it work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

**jq** + **bash** solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
jstring='[{"userQuery":"select name from abc;","user":"abc"},{"userQuery":"select name from xyz;","user":"xyz"},{"userQuery":"select name from ppp;","user":"ppp"}]'

while IFS=$'\t' read -r user query; do
    msg="User: ${user} is running : ${query}"
    mail -s "User query" "youremail@gmail.com" <<< "$msg"
done < <(jq '.[] | [.user,.userQuery] | @tsv' <<< "$jstring")
```

Comment: The above code did not work as expected, the code which Glenn has posted is working as expected. Please check the output, it is not working as expected.

Comment: @PanwarS87, at first, it works fine in terms of parsing and processing. Secondly, your expected output(as you said) was not clear. It was *I want two variable "user" & "query" for each array and store that info* - which does not look/sound clear. So I've done the man and crucial work. So, your claim sounds as preconceived

Comment: Sorry, I might sound unclear but when I ran the above code I am getting the below output.   User: "abc\tselect name from abc;" is running :
User: "xyz\tselect name from xyz;" is running :
User: "ppp\tselect name from ppp;" is running :   I may be missing something here or may be IFS is not working as expected.